# Up arrow key gets stuck while playing NFS Hot Pursuit

Tags: technical-issues, need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2010

hello, so I am playing NFS Hot Pursuit, it was initially fine and dandy, unfortunately after couple of days of playing, my uparrow/accelerate key started getting stuck while racing. I do press a lot the uparrow key, almost the entire time, and the left and right key occasionally to move sideways. Unfortunately the uparrow key freezes out once pressed, and it keeps on going on and on, for something like 2 to 3 minutes. After that it becomes unstuck, and then if I press it again, it gets stuck again for 2 to 3 min. The problem is I can not press the back/reverse key, as a result I have problems navigating the car around bends. And even after I manage to finish the game, the uparrow refuses to halt.  I have to wait for 5 min(sometimes) for it to unstuck, to enter into another race.

So, is this issue a software issue or my keyboard has weared out. Has anybody faced this problem before?By the way I am playing in Steam. Thanks.

Comment: Is the actual physical key on the keyboard pushed down too ? If that's the case, popping it out and cleaning it should be enough.

Comment: The problem occurs during gameplay, for any other activity, its fine, by the way its an Acer laptop/ultrabook ~ I am not expecting much.

Comment: If you can use the key fine in other games and it doesn't stay pushed down after releasing it, I would suspect a problem with the game more than anything.

Comment: Plug in an external keyboard and give it a bash.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau The keyboard is fine with other game such as NFS Shift,but there is something going on while I Hot Pursuit.

Comment: @Frank V ~ bash as in physical bashing or is it just to clearup the stuck keys.

Comment: @motiur, "give it a bash" means to try it. See if the same problem occurs.

Comment: It's actually weird but this has happened to me with another NFS game.  It is related to the game since I have tried different keyboards, but never did figure out why it happens.  I just stopped playing it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem with NFS Most Wanted. My solution? Get a new keyboard! Here is why:

Some keyboards are not able to handle multiple key inputs in certain areas (like the arrow keys) at the same time. This can either result in the last key pushed not responding or the first keeps hanging (your case) after letting go. Sometimes pressing it again may fix it. This issue is pretty rare and I encountered it with only two games in the past 15 years (I played a lot of games).

You can always try a different (better) keyboard to check on any differences, if that's no good either then you can be pretty sure it is something wonky in the game config or some incompatibility in the hardware.

Proposed solutions:

- Try cleaning it first (cheapest)
- Try a different keyboard
- Reinstalling the game can never hurt

Comment: New keyboard, or get a controller